# ¿Por qué muestra NaN?

Tags: javascript

```js
function A() {
  
  this.nombre = 'Stack Overflow';
  this.age = 14;
  this.community = true;
  
  this.funcionar = (function() {
    
    console.log(this.age * 2);
    
  })();
  

  
}

var b = new A();
```

Se supone que está dentro del contexto o no? Por qué me deuvelve NaN ,envez de 28?

Answer (score 6):

No es el mismo contexto, la función anónima tiene su propio contexto
Tienes que pasarle la variable a la función

```js
function A() {
  
  this.nombre = 'Stack Overflow';
  this.age = 14;
  this.community = true;
  
  this.funcionar = (function(age) {
    
    console.log(age * 2);
    
  })(this.age);
  

  
}

var b = new A();
```

Comment: Gracias Lato, también lo resolvi con mm.bind(this)();